# Username obfuscates content

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, user-interface, display-names

[image: Username overlapping with other content]

[image: Another example]

This username:

- obfuscates content
- distracts the reader
- is not easy to find on SO users tab (I gave up)
- generates compicated urls (copy pasted from browser): https://stackoverflow.com/users/419/k%CC%A8%CC%A9%CC%AD%CD%9A%CC%98%CC%97%CC%BB%CC%9E%CD%88%CD%96%CC%99%CD%99e%CD%9C%CD%A1%CC%97%CC%A6%CC%BC%CC%B3%CC%A3%CC%A6v%CC%A2%CC%9D%CC%9F%CC%97%CC%B1%CC%AF%CD%89

Is there any reason why we should allow usernames like this?

(Any way to notify this user of this discussion?)

Comment: He reads Meta with some regularity, I believe, so he'll probably see this. If not, you can leave a comment to one of his recent answers. At any rate, how do you propose "disallowing" user names like this? Do you mean on a case-by-case basis, or do you mean with some type of automatic rejection?

Comment: Some type of automatic rejection.

Comment: Related: [What are the rules and community thoughts about a non-easy username?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/263086/what-are-the-rules-and-community-thoughts-about-a-non-easy-username)

Comment: Your own user name contains unicode too.

Comment: see i found him on SO's user tab http://postimg.org/image/tbd5g9at9/

Comment: @Donaudampfschifffreizeitfahrt, forbidding unicode is definitely not the solution, and I didn't mean to criticize anyone for doing that. My question was more whether this was ok or not and what we can do about it.

Comment: I guess he was inspired by the classic http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3182664

Comment: For info; I don't view this as a bug, any more than it would be a "bug" if someone uses an inappropriate avatar.

Comment: @Donaudampfschifffreizeitfahrt: there are good reasons and bad reasons to use Unicode. The OP has a good reason: that is his surname. The other user (whose username I am not sure how to type...) does not seem to have a valid reason to use Unicode, aside from looking cool or annoying.

Comment: How are you guys so sure that's not his actual name? Maybe his parents were 1337 h4ckers or something.

Comment: Aw you folks are no fun :) But fair enough, was fun while it lasted and it wasn't done intentionally to cripple your viewing experience. I guess it'll take a wee while for the change to arrive here.

Comment: @Kev - I have to admit, I was moderately entertained by all the creative ways your former name wrecked formatting on old mod messages and tools.

Answer (score 15):

I will contact the user and change the display name manually for now; allowing unicode names is important, and most of the time it is used responsibly, but yes; this flexibility can be abused and I think that *deliberately* disrupting the UI (rather than simply expressing a desired display name) qualifies as such.

Answer (score 10):

I don't think automatic rejection is the solution. It's great that usernames aren't limited to alphanumeric characters, but misuse like this could lead to the feature being taken away.

The first step should be to ask the person to change their name to something less disruptive. If they do not respond to that, raise a moderator flag. [Moderators can change the username.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164109/can-moderators-ban-flag-inappropriate-profile-pictures)

Comment: This is _misuse_? If the system allows something it is, by definition, not misuse. As they are no guidelines, even though it's allowed, it can't be misuse. I also don't understand how this is disruptive at all. It's barely obscuring anything.

Comment: Also see [Kill Unicode bidirectional override in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131818/kill-unicode-bidirectional-override-in-comments). Apparently, Mod names were being spoofed.

Comment: @Ben: *If the system allows something it is, by definition, not misuse"* - [ask Weev about that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weev). He used AT&T's pubic server to gather email addresses, and he got 41 months in US Federal for it...

Comment: @Ben ["misuse: An incorrect, improper or unlawful use of something."](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/misuse). Something being *technically possible* does not automatically imply that it is correct, proper, and lawful. For instance, supermarket self checkouts "allow" you to take something without paying, but that would be "misuse" of that system.

Comment: @Ben: then we should allow answers with spam links. The system allows you to post those.

Comment: We're not talking about e-mail spam though are we @jww (etc.) we're talking about a tiny amount of Zalgo in a username... conflating the two is slightly ridiculous.

Comment: @Ben - I'm not sure what you mean about email spam. I'm just saying that using a system as designed could still get you in trouble. But anyway, I don't have a dog in this fight. I don't care about Unicode names, and they have never offended me. This question should probably be closed as a dup of one of the past discussions....

Answer (score -8):

> obfuscates content

Barely, it's still readable. Kev's reputation is obscured but that really doesn't matter.

> distracts the reader

Distracts you... I don't find it distracting.

> is not easy to find on SO users tab (I gave up)

You could have just clicked on the username. There are plenty of other ways of making yourself unfindable on the /users page.

> generates compicated urls (copy pasted from browser): https://stackoverflow.com/users/419/k%CC%A8%CC%A9%CC%AD%CD%9A%CC%98%CC%97%CC%BB%CC%9E%CD%88%CD%96%CC%99%CD%99e%CD%9C%CD%A1%CC%97%CC%A6%CC%BC%CC%B3%CC%A3%CC%A6v%CC%A2%CC%9D%CC%9F%CC%97%CC%B1%CC%AF%CD%89

Not sure why this is a problem at all. Are you typing out the URL? You can truncate this to `https://stackoverflow.com/users/419` if you want and it'll work.

> Is there any reason why we should allow usernames like this?

Is there any valid reason why we should disallow them? It's a username; it's not offensive; it's not hurting anyone; it's not causing any real problems...

Answer (score -20):

> > This username:
> >     obfuscates content

Not the username, the way SE shows them. Actually, it's an UI bug. It's like SQL injection: It's not your fault that your nickname is 'DROP DATABASE SYSTEM;'

> > distracts the reader

Primarily opinion based. For some people every non-ASCII characters may be disturbing. For others, the unicorns can be as well.

> > is not easy to find on SO users tab (I gave up)

You wouldn't be able to find user 'John' as well (I think) because there are so many of them...

> > generates compicated urls

The user id in URL is optional. I know it's included for SEO purposes, but maybe in such cases it makes simply no sense? Just like in above points, it's not the user's fault that SE generates such URLs.

Comment: _"It's not the user's fault he pulled the gun's trigger."_ If the user intentionally chooses a name with such characters, it damn sure is the user's responsibility.

Comment: @Don, sure. And if I put kerosene instead of diesel in my car, it's the car manufacturer's fault when it does not start afterwards.

Comment: You've completely missed the analogy. If you put your kerosene in your car, you car is driving good, but other car gets broken because you use keresone, it is manufacturer's fault. Anyway, it's a bit of hypocrisy to criticize people for using Unicode when you self use it in your user name ;)

Comment: @Don, I did not criticize anything (except your answer), and certainly not the use of Unicode. There is, however, an obvious difference between acute accents that are real parts of my actual name and "Zalgo" effects. I suspect you may be disingenuous here.

Comment: No, there's no difference. Both are completely legal unicode characters, and if some system claim to support unicode, it should support unicode, and not only a tiny part of it. 
It's not the only place where the UI of SE is broken.

Comment: An attitude like yours is exactly why the team could reconsider allowing Unicode usernames.

Comment: Good. Better do something good that everything wrong :)